# How do I get an inline style applied to a class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can any body help me get an inline style( specifically **left**) of a class using jQuery?

Comment: jQuery's documentation is quite good, you just have to read it: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/

Comment: Do you mean get the current CSS `left` value for an element that has a specific class or do you want to get the `left` declaration for a CSS class like: `.my-class { left : 50px; }`?

Comment: @Jasper, What I mean is the style rendered by the browser or something(i.e. when you use inspect element on gchrome). I'm using masonry by Desandro and I want to get the value of left rendered after  the script is done. offset() and position() is not working since they're all the same. 

For example, <div class="dang" style="left: 1000px"> I want to get 1000px.

Comment: @Adrengski Then you want `css()`: http://api.jquery.com/css

Answer (score 4):

Form a class?

```
$('.yourclass').css("left");
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/L7X9B/

Comment: What I mean was style wasn't declared on the <style></style> part. It adds up on the code itself like <div class="myStyle" style="left:1000px">. I want to get that style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
var leftPosition = $(element).offset().left;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get inline style you can use normal properties:

```
$(".myStyle").each( function(){
    console.log( this.style.left );
});
```